# Passing custom init parameter to Vaadin

Tags: java, javascript, vaadin

I have an application written in Javascript which embeds Vaadin application. Since it takes a while for Vaadin to load, I need to have some way to notify js application that it has been loaded. To do that I need to pass some id of embedding app to Vaadin at startup. 
The best way would be to pass it by configuration

```
vaadin.initApplication("embedingDiv", this.config);
```

but Vaadin seem to ignore any custom variables. When I try to access to init parameters with

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getConfiguration().getInitParameters());
```

I get something like that:

```
UI=com.example.tabletest.TabletestUI, resourceCacheTime=3600, productionMode=false, legacyPropertyToString=false, heartbeatInterval=300, closeIdleSessions=false, widgetset=com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet
```

which are paremeters that I set in my config file, but other parameters set there seem to be ignored.

Is it possible to pass config parameters this way? Or any other, I just need them to be accessible in `init` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply adding URI parameter to `browserDetailsUrl` field.

```
pConfig.browserDetailsUrl += "?foo=bar";
```

I can access it with

```
VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getParameter("foo");
```

or

```
request.getParameter("foo");
```

in `init` method.